# Clearing SectionsCollection in LiveCharts for WPF

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I'm building a WPF data visualization tool with the Geared version of **LiveCharts**.
I have a SectionsCollection object named `SectionsCollection` that I need to reload as the data changes. I run the following code segment before reassigning to `SectionsCollection`.

```
        try
        {
            if (SectionsCollection != null && SectionsCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                SectionsCollection.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Status += "Error in clearing SectionsCollection.\n"+e;
        }
        SectionsCollection = new SectionsCollection();
```

The following error occurs intermittently on the `SectionsCollection.Clear();` line, with the label **NullReferenceException occurred**.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in LiveCharts.Wpf.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I check that `SectionsCollection` is not null and is not empty, why is this error coming up?

This error seems to occur for VisualsCollection and SeriesCollection types as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find out how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try add flag to prevent unwanted multiple exec. in your process:

```
 bool collIsBusy = false;
        try
        {
            if (SectionsCollection != null && SectionsCollection.Count > 0 && !collIsBusy)
            {
                collIsBusy = true; //flag to prevent throttling multiple executions
                SectionsCollection.Clear();
                collIsBusy = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Status += "Error in clearing SectionsCollection.\n" + e;
        }
        SectionsCollection = new SectionsCollection();
```